# Haskell beginner order function

Tags: haskell

My code:

```
isOrdered :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
isOrdered mark xs =(head xs) `mark`(head(tail xs))
```

Compiles perfectly but when I try to call it with

```
isOrdered < [1,2,3]
```

I get an error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `(a0 -> a0 -> Bool) -> [a0] -> Bool'
            with actual type `[t0]'
In the second argument of `(<)', namely `[1, 2, 3]'
In the expression: isOrdered < [1, 2, 3]
In an equation for `it': it = isOrdered < [1, 2, 3]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5):

Since `<` is infix, you have to wrap it in parens. This converts it to be prefixed.

```
1 < 2 ==> (<) 1 2
1 + 5 ==> (+) 1 5
```

Then you're code becomes

```
isOrdered (<) [1, 2, 3]
```

This is actually part of a more general concept of sectioning. You can completely convert an infix operator to prefix with parens, or partially apply it like this

```
\x -> x + 1 ===> (+1)
\x -> 2 ^ x ===> (2^)
```

The only place where this goes a bit pear-shaped is with `-`. Since `-` is a super special prefix operator defined by the Haskell language, you can't do `(-2)`, since it's not clear whether this is a section or a number. Haskell chooses a number, but if you want a section, there is a function `subtract`.

```
\x -> x - 2 ==> subtract 2
```

Comment: Man, unary `-` is an ugly hack. I personally wouldn't mind writing negation as `0 - x`.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
isOrdered (<) [1,2,3]
```

Not sure why, though. It’s a general thing:

```
Prelude> :type <
<interactive>:1:1: parse error on input `<'
Prelude> :type (<)
(<) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
```

I’m sure others will explain.

Answer (score 2):

When passing an operator to a higher level function, you have to surround it with parentheses:

```
isOrdered (<) [1, 2, 3]
```

You also have to do this for partially applied operators

```
map (== 2) [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question, but just a stylistic tip: idiomatic Haskell code should use pattern matching instead of `head`/`tail`.  Pattern matching statically ensures that you don't accidentally try to access inexistent elements.

The way you would write your function using pattern matching is:

```
isOrdered :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe Bool
isOrdered mark (x:y:_) = Just (x `mark` y)
isOrdered _    _       = Nothing
```

Note that I've included a case for when the list does not contain two elements and wrapped the result in a `Maybe`.  This prevents run-time errors by forcing you to handle that case.